# Selenium Grid 2 node tests do stop running

Tags: python, selenium

I've configured a selenium 2.25.0 hub inside a VM running Ubuntu to run my test suite.  If I use a node within the VM my tests run through to completion just fine.  The problem I have occurs when I use a node on the host machine (Windows 7) and subscribe to that hub.  The first test executes without problem then a blank window is opened by web-driver and it hangs until the node reclaims it but that's not all.  The site to test, also on the VM, becomes inaccessible although it's still a running process on the VM, which forces me to restart it.  It's not a port forwarding issue I presume as I can access the website manually from the host as much as I like but when I run a test I get one test then hang.

The quit() function seems to be the start of it.  If I remove that I can execute up to my configured allowance of parallel tests but after that you have to wait for the hub to reclaim to run more but it doesn't botch up the website.

Is there a better way to close a browser when you're done with it or is there something I'm missing here/haven't tried? Thanks in advance.